# Confusion about Lang's Conjecture

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry

I've been reading the following Paper (https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.06818) on arithmetic hyperbolicity. We say that a scheme $X/\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ is arithmetically hyperbolic over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ is for every $\mathbb{Z}$-finitely generated subring $A\subset \overline{\mathbb{Q}}$, the set of $A$-rational points is finite, i.e. $X(A)$ is finite. In this Paper, the mention a conjecture (Conjecture 1.1), in which claims that $X$ is arithmetically hyperbolic over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ if and only if for every abelian variety $A$ over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$, every morphism $A\rightarrow X$ over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ is constant.

However, I am confused what this would mean in the case that $X$ is an abelian variety itself. There exist elliptic curves of rank one over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$, i.e. $X(\mathbb{Z})$ is a finite torsion group. However, the map $X\rightarrow X, x\mapsto 2x$ is not constant. Therefore $X$ should not have only finitely many integral points. Since this seems like an obvious counterexample, I must misunderstand something very basic about this conjecture. What is it?

Comment: An abelian variety will not be arithmetically hyperbolic.

Comment: Evidently, Abelian varieties are not hyperbolic. I’m very puzzled by your last paragraph. Surely, if $X(\Bbb Z)$ is finite, that’s rank zero. And I do not believe your statement about elliptic curves over $\overline{\Bbb Q}$. Every such will already be defined over a number field $K$, so have finite rank over $K$, but you’ll have to argue hard to persuade me that the rank never increases, no matter the extension $K'\supset K$.

Comment: As alluded to above, a non-zero abelian variety is not arithmetically hyperbolic. What you write in your last paragraph is not right. The $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$-points of an elliptic curve $E$ do not form a finite rank group. Indeed, if $A$ is a non-zero abelian variety over a number field $K$, then there is a finite field extension $L/K$ such that the rank of $A(L)$ is bigger than the rank of $A(K)$. On another note: you might find https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.11981 helpful to read.